# General (non-server-specific) HTTP server test suite?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, httpserver

I'm looking for a test suite to test an HTTP server for standards compliance. The test suite should therefor not be server-specific, like Apache's HTTP server test suite.

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SPECWEB99](http://www.spec.org/web99/) sounds like it tests HTTP server compliance; unfortunately, [it isn't free](http://www.spec.org/order.html).  Here's a snippet from [their FAQ](http://www.spec.org/web99/docs/faq.html):

> SPECweb99 provides the source code for an HTTP 1.0/1.1 load generator that will make random selections from a predetermined distribution. The benchmark defines a particular set of files to be used as the static files that will be obtained by GETs from the server, thus defining a particular benchmark workload.
>
> The benchmark does not provide any of the web server software. That is left up to the tester. Any web server software that supports HTTP 1.0 and/or HTTP 1.1 can be used. However, it should be noted that variations in implementations may lead to differences in observed performance.

This [big list of over 400 web testing tools](http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html) might be of assistance to you as well.  I wasn't able to find anything on there specifically for server compliance testing, but maybe you'll have better luck with a different ctrl-F on the page.  On the other hand, if you need a stress-tester, you'll find a ton of them there.

Comment: SPECweb99 is a performance test suite, and according to their web site has been retired. Thanks for the pointer to the web testing tool links, I'll have a look there.

Answer (score 0):

[Co-Advisor](http://coad.measurement-factory.com/) is an HTTP compliance + test suite. Co-Advisor is [not free](http://coad.measurement-factory.com/details.html#pricing), unless your implementation passes all Co-Advisor tests the very first time (no one did so far).

You'll find a little more background on Co-Advisor in this paper: [HTTP Compliance and W3C QA](http://www.w3.org/2001/01/qa-ws/pp/alex-rousskov-measfact).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Unfortunatly, according to the manufacturer, CoAdvisor needs the tested server to act as an HTTP proxy "for now". Hopefully they're working on that...